# How to evaluate the integral $\int_0^{\ln3} e^{x-e^x}\,\mathrm dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function

How to evaluate the following definite integral? $$\int_0^{\ln3} e^{x-e^x}\,\mathrm dx.$$

Should I use some sort of U Substitution?

Comment: Write the integrand as $e^x/e^{\color{maroon}{e^x}}$ and let $\color{maroon}{u=e^x}$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the substitution $u=\mathrm{e}^{x}$, and $\mathrm{d}u=\mathrm{e}^x$, then we get
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\ln3}\mathrm{e}^{x-\mathrm{e}^x}\,\mathrm{d}x &= \int_1^3\mathrm{e}^{-u}\,\mathrm{d}u \\
&=\left[-\mathrm{e}^{-u}\right]_1^3 \\
&=\frac{\mathrm{e}^2-1}{\mathrm{e}^3}
\end{align*}